# GeoJSON parse node

Tags: node.js, geojson

I am getting an 500 error 'unexpected problem has occurred' when I parse the GeoJSON data from this [weather API](https://api.weather.gov/points/39.7456,-97.0892) site using node app.

The code is a simple proxy server to receive request from client for weather info on a particular site and process an async request to the weatherAPI, when the response is received its send to the client. When I replace the URL with something that returns JSON it works. The issue is when the response data is GeoJSON.

Appreciate if anyone help shed some light on how to parse the GeoJSON response in node JavaScript.

Thank you in advance.

### Here is my node app code:

```
function initialize() {
    // Setting URL and headers for request
    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.weather.xxx/points/39.7456,-97.0892',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'request'
        }
    };
    // Return new promise
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // Do async job
        request.get(options, function(err, resp, body) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(JSON.parse(body));
            }
        })
    })
}

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   var initializePromise = initialize();
   initializePromise.then(function(result) {
       var geoDetails = result;
       console.log("Initialized Geo details");
       // Use user details from here
       console.log(geoDetails);
       res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
       res.write('request successfully proxied!' + '\n' + 
          JSON.stringify(geoDetails, true, 2));
       res.end();
   }, function(err) {
       console.log(err);
   })
}).listen(9000);
```

### Here is the GeoJSON data :

```
{
    "@context": [
        "...",
        {
            "wx": "...",
            "s": "...",
            "geo": "...",
            "unit": "...",
            "@vocab": "...",
            "geometry": {
                "@id": "s:GeoCoordinates",
                "@type": "geo:wktLiteral"
            },
            "city": "s:addressLocality",
            "state": "s:addressRegion",
            "distance": {
                "@id": "s:Distance",
                "@type": "s:QuantitativeValue"
            },
            "bearing": {
                "@type": "s:QuantitativeValue"
            },
            "value": {
                "@id": "s:value"
            },
            "unitCode": {
                "@id": "s:unitCode",
                "@type": "@id"
            },
            "forecastOffice": {
                "@type": "@id"
            },
            "forecastGridData": {
                "@type": "@id"
            },
            "publicZone": {
                "@type": "@id"
            },
            "county": {
                "@type": "@id"
            }
        }
    ],
    "id": "...api.weather.xxx/points/39.7456,-97.0892",
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -97.0892,
            39.7456
        ]
    },
    "properties": {
        "@id": "...api.weather.xxx/points/39.7456,-97.0892",
        "@type": "wx:Point",
        "cwa": "TOP",
        "forecastOffice": "...api.weather.xxx/offices/TOP",
        "gridX": 31,
        "gridY": 80,
        ...
        "relativeLocation": {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -97.086661,
                    39.679376
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "city": "Linn",
                "state": "KS",
                "distance": {
                    "value": 7366.9851976444,
                    "unitCode": "unit:m"
                },
                "bearing": {
                    "value": 358,
                    "unitCode": "unit:degrees_true"
                }
            }
        },
       ...
    }
}
```

I am interested in getting all the Properties in plain text or JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your headers to `accept` JSON.

```
var options = {
    url: 'https://api.weather.gov/points/39.7456,-97.0892',
    headers: {
        'user-agent': 'request',
        'accept': 'application/json'
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, i added that 'accept': 'application/json' and now I am able to get the 'status OK', but no content yet.

Comment: And in additon to the above I also changed from options.url to options.uri and it worked. Thank you so much!